# List all System Modems 

Tags: c#, .net, modem, telephony

Is there a way in managed code to list the Modem/Telephony devices installed on the system?
If .Net does not have a way, could you point me in a direction?

Comment: Modems?  I remember those... Though I also remember floppies and printers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WMI will contain all the information you need in the `Win32_POTSModem` class.  In C# or .Net, you can utilize the `System.Management` namespace to query WMI.

Within .Net, you can use [MgmtclassGen.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wkebaxa(VS.80).aspx) from the platform SDK to generate a class object representing the WMI class.

The command line would be like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\mgmtclassgen.exe Win32_POTSModem /L CS /P c:\POTSModem\Win32_POTSModem.cs
```

and then you can use that in your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using ROOT.CIMV2.Win32;

public class MyClass
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    foreach (POTSModem modem in POTSModem.GetInstances()) {
      Console.WriteLine(modem.Description);
    }
  }
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
ThinkPad Modem - Internal Modem
        Speed: 56000
```

You also might want to take a look at this article: [CodeProject: How To: (Almost) Everything In WMI via C# - Part 3: Hardware.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EverythingInWmi03.aspx).  The author has created a simple class wrapper around WMI objects similar to MgmtclassGen.exe, but its all done for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just some thoughts for future generations.

@Christopher_G_Lewis provided very good solution.
But before using WMI we have to check that `Windows Management Instrumentation` (`WMI`, service name `Winmgmt`) is working (*how to do it?*). Of course, MS recommends don't touch this service, because it's part of system stuff, but people switch it off sometimes.

Moreover, sometimes it may be helpful to [check WMI version](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;313653) before using it.

If you want to **get modems list** which are **connected** at the moment, you can check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139035/find-gsm-modem-port-in-c/7576498#7576498). It works slowly, but shows all connected modems and excludes `Null modem cables`.