# Find gsm modem port in c#

Tags: c#, port

I want to loop through the available ports:
    System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
to find if a port is used by a gsm modem.
Any idea please.

Comment: I guess you know how to communicate with this device (I don't) - there should be some simple operation (say asking for device version/serial number) you can send to each port to find the device

Comment: Can I send AT Commands to a port that's not connected to a modem?

Comment: sure - why not, you won't see any response thats IMHO all

Comment: You would be unlucky to get an adverse response to sending an AT command to a port that is not connected.  Either the port has nothing on it - in which case no response will be given, in the event that something is connected to the port (decreasingly likely nowadays) - you would have to match the serial port settings and the expected messages that this device is waiting for.

Answer (score 6):

What I did in my application for one similar task:

1. To check that a modem is connected to particular port you can send AT command into this port.
   This function below returns true if we found a modem on the current COM port:

   ```
   private bool CheckExistingModemOnComPort(SerialPort serialPort)
   {
       if ((serialPort == null) || !serialPort.IsOpen)
           return false;

       // Commands for modem checking
       string[] modemCommands = new string[] { "AT",       // Check connected modem. After 'AT' command some modems autobaud their speed.
                                               "ATQ0" };   // Switch on confirmations
       serialPort.DtrEnable = true;    // Set Data Terminal Ready (DTR) signal 
       serialPort.RtsEnable = true;    // Set Request to Send (RTS) signal

       string answer = "";
       bool retOk = false;
       for (int rtsInd = 0; rtsInd < 2; rtsInd++)
       {
           foreach (string command in modemCommands)
           {
               serialPort.Write(command + serialPort.NewLine);
               retOk = false;
               answer = "";
               int timeout = (command == "AT") ? 10 : 20;

               // Waiting for response 1-2 sec
               for (int i = 0; i < timeout; i++)
               {
                   Thread.Sleep(100);
                   answer += serialPort.ReadExisting();
                   if (answer.IndexOf("OK") >= 0)
                   {
                       retOk = true;
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }
           // If got responses, we found a modem
           if (retOk)
               return true;

           // Trying to execute the commands without RTS
           serialPort.RtsEnable = false;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```
2. On the next stage we can collect some data from the modem.
   I used the following commands:

   - **ATQ0** - switch on confirmations (receive OK on each request)
   - **ATE0** - switch on echo
   - **ATI** - get modem details
   - **ATI3** - get extended modem details (not all modems supports this command)

Answer (score 0):

```
                // Check each Availble COM port
                foreach (string l_sport in l_available_ports)
                {
                    GlobalVars.g_serialport = GlobalFunc.OpenPort(l_sport, Convert.ToInt32(this.cboBaudRate.Text), Convert.ToInt32(this.cboDataBits.Text), Convert.ToInt32(this.txtReadTimeOut.Text), Convert.ToInt32(this.txtWriteTimeOut.Text));
                    if (GlobalVars.g_serialport.IsOpen)
                    {
                        GlobalVars.g_serialport.WriteLine("AT\r");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        string l_response = GlobalVars.g_serialport.ReadExisting();
                        if (l_response.IndexOf("OK") >= 0)
                        {
                            GlobalVars.g_serialport.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1\r");
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                            string l_response1 = GlobalVars.g_serialport.ReadExisting();
                            if (l_response1.IndexOf("OK") >= 0)
                            {
                                GlobalVars.g_PhoneNo = txt_PhNum.Text;
                                MessageBox.Show("Connected Successfully", "Connection", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                lblConnectionStatus.Text = "Phone Connected Successfully.";
                                btnOK.Enabled = false;
                                btnDisconnect.Enabled = true;

                                GlobalVars.g_serialport.WriteLine("AT+CGSN\r");
                                Thread.Sleep(500);
                                string l_imei = GlobalVars.g_serialport.ReadExisting();
                                Console.WriteLine("Modem IMEI:" + l_imei);
                                if (l_imei.IndexOf("OK", 1) > 0)
                                {
                                    l_imei = l_imei.Replace("AT+CGSN\r\r\n", null);
                                    l_imei = l_imei.Replace("\r\n\r\nOK\r\n", null);
                                    lbl_ModemIMEI.Text = l_imei;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    lblConnectionStatus.Text = "Phone Connected Successfully. Error reading IMEI.";
                                }
                                EnableSMSNotification(GlobalVars.g_serialport);

                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("No AT+CMGF cmd response");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("No AT cmd response");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No Phone At:" + l_sport);
                    }
                }
```